# How to remove all entry from dropdown except first one

Tags: jquery

My dropdown html say look like this

```
<select id="models" ">
    <option id = "remove" value="">--Select--</option>
    <option id = "remove" value="0">R8</option>
    <option id = "remove" value="1">Quattro</option>
    <option id = "remove" value="2">A6 hatchback</option>
</select>
```

i know how to remove all entry from dropdown and add new data again as per below code.

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("YourUrl")',function(data){

     var dropdown=$('#models');
    dropdown.empty();  
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        dropdown.append(
            $('<option>', {
                value: item.valueField,
                text: item.DisplayField
            }, '</option>'))
          }
         )});
```

but i like to know how to keep this row `<option id = "remove" value="">--Select--</option>` when removing all other item from dropdown ?

thanks

Comment: `id` value should be unique (_for the whole document_)

Comment: `$('#models option:gt(0)').remove();`

Comment: Faster: `$('#models").get(0).options.length=1;`

Comment: @mplungjan Wow. What does that do?

Comment: It removes all options except the first

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, do not duplicate `id` values (this causes JavaScript to get confused), but you can do so with `class`es. Secondly, you can just use:

```
$("option:not(:first)").remove();
```

Also note, you are not closing the tag correctly:

```
<select id="models" ">
<!------------------^ remove this
```

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("#models").find("option:not(:first)").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="models">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="0">R8</option>
  <option value="1">Quattro</option>
  <option value="2">A6 hatchback</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can filter out the item with value of empty string with a selector:

```
$("#models option:not([value=''])").remove();
```

This ensures that all other options will be removed regardless of which index your empty value option is positioned at.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `:gt()` selector with parameter `0`, substituting `className` `"remove"` for duplicate `id`s `"remove"` at `option` elements

```js
$("#models option:gt(0)").remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<select id="models">
            <option class="remove" value="">--Select--</option>
            <option class="remove" value="0">R8</option>
            <option class="remove" value="1">Quattro</option>
            <option class="remove" value="2">A6 hatchback</option>
</select>
```